# Two way data binding with EditText

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I am working on a simple Android App using Kotlin. I want to use databindings, but I cannot get them work with an `EditText`

This is my XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="de.knerd.applicationmanager.models.AgencyModel"/>
        <variable name="agency" type="AgencyModel"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_agency"
            tools:context="de.knerd.applicationmanager.activities.AddAgencyActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                       android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:labelFor="@+id/name"
                    android:hint="@string/agency_name"
                    android:text="@={agency.name}"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my Model class

```
package de.knerd.applicationmanager.models

import android.databinding.BaseObservable
import android.databinding.Bindable
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.ForeignCollection
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField
import com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable
import de.knerd.applicationmanager.BR

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "agency")
class AgencyModel : BaseObservable() {

    @DatabaseField(unique = true, canBeNull = false)
    @get:Bindable
    @set:Bindable
    var name: String? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
        }
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    @get:Bindable
    var id: Int = 0
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    @get:Bindable
    var agents: ForeignCollection<AgentModel>? = null
}
```

And this is the part that binds the model to the view

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ContentAddAgencyBinding>(this, R.layout.content_add_agency)
    binding.agency = AgencyModel()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_agency)
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

When I try to access the properties of model that is in the binding I get a null value. The Code I use is this

```
private fun save(): Boolean {
    try {
        val agency = binding.agency
        Log.d("Name", agency.name)
        return true
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem, it was caused by me binding to the wrong layout. The correct Code is as follows.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityAddAgencyBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_add_agency)
    binding.agency = AgencyModel()
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

In both cases I had to bind to the activity layout

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Binding the way it was meant to be Knerd. Two-Way binding is intended so that you can access objects or fields from code without ever having to reference the UI code. By you doing the binding.agency you are no different then findViewById() and you are defeating the purpose of binding.

Fix your binding problems first. Use BaseObservable for your object model and it should stay up to date with whatever values change on the screen.

Then when you save it should be nothing more then accessing the local variable.

```
private fun save(): Boolean {
    try {

        Log.d("Name", localObservableAgency.name)
        return true
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return false
    }
}
```

//not sure what this method is for, guessing you were try catching null. Better way would be to just do a null check on the object as catching exception by accessing null value is heavy and doesn't add value. Also Kotlin is null safe language, so you are either losing your value on the binding maybe by setting it to null to begin with or something is coded weirdly here as you have to intentionally make an object nullable if you keep a local copy. However, you weren't keeping a local copy you were just newing one up inline and accessing via binding later as if it was your repository of variables haha.

So long story short, is use data binding the way it was intended to be used and you won't have a problem. That is probably why someone down voted you is my guess.

Comment: Well, how am I supposed to add the binding to the view then? And it was not for null check, it was for catching SQLException

Comment: Also the code I used is the sample code by Google adjusted to my classes.

Comment: The only place you should be touching the binding is in the onCreate to set your observable variables for the XML. This is a temporary hack until Google iterates their binding process to not require it. If you are touching binding in your save routine then you are using binding incorrectly. I'm just trying to help you, but you can certainly do it however you like. Glad you found your issue though.

Comment: Sorry, that I was a bit rude. Do you know why the official Google sample has it wrong?

Comment: no worries, there are a couple of reasons. Android is new to data binding. They have relied on 3rd party to do it for years. Microsoft and other languages have been doing it much longer and cleaner. Google has not gotten everything to work in binding yet so as a work-around for things that cannot be bound properly they are having you access via binding. For example, error handling can get really messy in binding, it can be done, but it is messy, so some choose to do it through binding accessors until binding is further along. It's really early still so will be some bad practices for a bit

Comment: Most languages do not require any onCreate wire up, you just mark your objects as INotifyPropertyChanged or ICommand or other flags to indicate it is a binding value and the UI knows it's datacontext can access directly. But this is Googles first attempt so hopefully it will continue to grow into clean data binding

Comment: That is a bit sad, I worked with databindings in WPF and UWP for a long time and there it works really nicely. And the Android binding library seems a bit early staged but makes the work easier, so I think I will stick with it

Comment: Yes totally agree. It is exciting to see it finally adopted but it is pretty ugly right now. I also worked with WPF and Silverlight for years and appreciate the cleanliness of data binding code. Glad to hear more people jumping on adopting. :) Happy coding my friend